# Segmentation fault while merging two sorted linked list in c++

Tags: c++

I'm solving this following problem.

You’re given the pointer to the head nodes of two sorted linked lists. The data in both lists will be sorted in ascending order. Change the next pointers to obtain a single, merged linked list which also has data in ascending order. Either head pointer given may be null meaning that the corresponding list is empty.
When i run my code it gives me segmentation fault.Here p and q corresponds to the head pointers.

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* mergeLists(SinglyLinkedListNode* p, SinglyLinkedListNode* q) {

    SinglyLinkedListNode *s=NULL;
    SinglyLinkedListNode *newhead;
  
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        return q;
    }
    else if(q==NULL)
    {
        return p;
    }
        
   if(p!=NULL && q!=NULL)
   {
    if(p->data<=q->data)
    {
        s=p;
        p=s->next;

    }

    else if(q->data>=p->data)
    {
        s=q;
        q=s->next;
    }
   }

    newhead = s;

    while(p || q)
    {
        if(p->data<=q->data)
        {
            s->next = p;
            s = p;
            p = s->next;
        }

        else if(q->data<=p->data)
        {
            s->next = q;
            s = q;
            q = s->next;
        }
    }

    if(p==NULL)
    {
       s->next = p;
    }
    else if(q==NULL)
    {
        s->next = q;
    }

    return newhead;

}
```

Comment: You check `while(p || q)` and then use `->data` on both `p` and `q`. This is UB if one of them is NULL

Comment: These three statements don't look right either `s->next = p; s = p; p = s->next;` You set `s->next` to `p` and then you set `p` to `s->next`. The net result is that `p` won't change,

Comment: `while(p || q)` -- Ask yourself what would happen if `p` and `q` are different lengths?  I suggest you draw on paper what is to be done before writing any code, since the code you're showing doesn't take care of that obvious case.

Comment: Pointers are tricky, it's very easy to write code that looks OK, but in fact isn't. Until you get familar it really does help to draw diagrams of what you want to do.

Comment: @cigien already pointed out a major issue with the code, just adding a nit-pick here: After you check the arguments for `NULL`, this third check is kind of redundant: `if(p!=NULL && q!=NULL)`, you've already ensured that neither is `NULL`